# Loop with two different execution intervals

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4

I'm combining codes for my university project. I am new to Python so this may not be best practice.

I have a code that has set up all the GPio pins etc, and then goes:

```
while True:
   #code measuring pressure here
   time.sleep(0.5)
```

This was my test code to ensure everything works fine, and now i want to add servo movement every few seconds, while keeping pressure measurement every 0.5s. This cannot be done with time.sleep but I am not sure how to implement scheduler.
I want something that will go:

```
while True:
  for t every 0.5s:
     #measure pressure
  for t every 2s:
     #move servo
end
```

Could I have some examples please?

Comment: Can you use multiple threads? One thread can measure pressure every 0.5 seconds, the other moves the servo every 2 seconds.

Comment: In the shown case, measure pressure every 0.5s and after every four measures (use a variable to count) additionally move servo.

Answer (score 1):

Since one of the periods is an exact multiple of the other, you can sleep 0.5 seconds between iterations, and then do something whenever you get to that multiple.

```
counter = 0
while True:
    # measure pressure
    if counter == 0:
        # move servo
    time.sleep(0.5)
    counter = (counter + 1) % 4
```

Comment: I think your comment suggesting threads is better. This answer can work given the OP's stated requirements. However, threading is more conducive to timers for these two operation (measure pressure, move servo) which can then be completely independent

Comment: I agree, I just don't know python multithreading well enough to write that answer. Also, threading will probably require a mutex. And since this is for an RPi environment, I'm not sure how well it works in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think that independent threads is the way to go with this. In that way the measure pressure and move servo operations can have independent intervals.

Consider this:

```
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock

glock = Lock()

def mp_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        with glock:
            print('Measuring pressure')
            pass # run pressure measurement code here

def ms_func():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        with glock:
            print('Moving servo')
            pass # run servo movement code here

for t in [Thread(target=f) for f in (ms_func, mp_func)]:
    t.start()

# the threads will run indefinitely so this effectively blocks the main program
t.join()
```

Note: I have added the Lock because I imagine that you wouldn't want the measure pressure and move servo operations running concurrently